# Метки на CalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendar

Возможно ли на стандартном `CalendarView` как-нибудь поставить метки (точки под числом) на определённые дни? Либо может есть какая-нибудь библиотечка с календарём, похожим на стандартный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Если есть необходимость выделить определенные дни, то можно воспользоваться методом:

```
setHighlightedDays(Calendar[] days)
```

По умолчанию дни выделятся полужирным шрифтом, однако можно так же изменить и цвет шрифта.

> They will be rendered in bold. You can tweak the color of the
>   highlighted days by overwriting mdtp_date_picker_text_highlighted

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же, если вы хотите выделением хотите подсказать пользователю, что только данные дни могут быть выбраны, то можно воспользоваться методом:

```
setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно ли скрыть верхнюю часть, которая отображает дату? upd: нашёл. спасибо, это вариант подходит

Comment: @kapmayn стандартной такой функции не нашел, но такое отображение наиболее близкое к дефолтному на android > 5.0